# Understanding a proof about regular cardinals from "Set Theory for the Working Mathematician"

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals

Consider the following proposition:

> If $\lambda$ is regular cardinal, $A \subseteq \lambda$ and $|A| < \lambda$ then there is $\alpha < \lambda$ such that $A \subseteq \alpha$.

Here's its proof taken from the book "Set Theory for the Working Mathematician" written by Krzysztof Ciesielski.

> Let $\beta$ be an order type of $A$ (with respect to the $\in$-ordering) and let $f\colon\beta\to A\subseteq\lambda$ be an order isomorphism. Notice that $\beta < \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$, since $|\beta| = |A| < \lambda = \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$. So the set $A = f(\beta)$ cannot be unbounded in $\lambda$. This implies the existence of an $\alpha < \lambda$ such that $\xi < \alpha$ for all $\xi \in A$. Thus $A \subseteq \alpha$.

I don't understand the following line:

> Notice that $\beta < \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$, since $|\beta| = |A| < \lambda = \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$.

Why would $|\beta| < \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$ imply $\beta < \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$?

Comment: Do you know that $cf(\lambda)$ is always a cardinal?

Comment: Since this is the definition of "regular" in some places, how do you define "regular"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila An infinite cardinal which is equal to its own cofinality.

Comment: And your definition of cofinality is..?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The cofinality of an ordinal $\alpha$ is the least ordinal $\beta$ so the there is a function $f\colon\beta\to\alpha$ where $f(\beta)$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know that $cf(\lambda)$ is a cardinal, you can argue as follows: if $\vert\beta\vert< cf(\lambda)$ then we must have $cf(\lambda)\ge\vert\beta\vert^+$ - but $\vert\beta\vert^+>\beta$. So we get $$\vert\beta\vert<cf(\lambda)\implies\beta<cf(\lambda)$$ as desired.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't quite understand why $|\beta|^+ > \beta$. It seems to be a fundamental fact I was missing.

Comment: I mean, intuitively it makes sense, but I'm still trying to come up with a proof.

Comment: I think I got it. But first we would need to know that for any ordinal $\alpha$ and any cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa \leq \alpha$ implies $\kappa \leq |\alpha|$.

Comment: @Jxt921 But that's immediate: Since $\kappa$ is a cardinal, if we were to have $\kappa>\vert\alpha\vert$ then there would be no injection from $\kappa$ to $\alpha$. But $\kappa\le\alpha$ means that there is such an injection.

Comment: I know. I just said that I needed this little lemma to prove that $|\beta|^+ > \beta$. Thank you for your help though.